# What am I doing wrong in this problem for encoding a string?

Tags: python, string, for-loop, replace, encoding

I have been trying to write this program for a  [codewars problem/kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/54b42f9314d9229fd6000d9c/train/python) which reads a string, and converts the string to a new string where each character in the new string is "(" if that character appears only once in the original string, or ")" if that character appears more than once in the original string. Ignore capitalization when determining if a character is a duplicate.

So, below is the small code I wrote, before starting to work towards the bigger part of the problem:

```
a = "Eren"
b = a.lower()
for i in b:
    c = b.count(i)
    print(c)
    if c == 1:
        d = b.replace(i, "(")
    else:
        d = b.replace(i, ")")

print(d)
```

I was expecting the output to be

```
)()(
```

But what I get is

```
ere(
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have two `print()` statements.

Comment: Yeah, that's my bad. I forgot to edit it out while posting here. I had written the `print(c)` statement so that I could keep track of the values being returned for larger strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to update the original string. If you don't, you are just over writing the previous value of `d` with new one. Since `b` is unchanged, you get `ere(`. Instead, do

```
a = "Eren"
b = a.lower()
for i in b:
    c = b.count(i)
    print(c)
    if c == 1:
        d = b.replace(i, "(")
        b=b.replace(i, "(")  #==== Replace the original string too
    else:
        d = b.replace(i, ")")
        b=b.replace(i, ")") #==== Replace the original string too

print(d)
```

Your output looks like:

```
)()(
```

But, it doesn't look a good idea to change the `b` value while iterating over it. Instead, do this:

```
a = "Eren"
b = a.lower()
d=''
for i in b:
    c = b.count(i)
    print(c)
    if c == 1:
        d += '('
    else:
        d+=')'
print(d)
```

Comment: The second method also will give the right result when a="b(" I believe. Should be "((" I believe, but pretty sure method 1 would give "))"

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest a different (and more efficient) implementation?

```
from collections import Counter

count = Counter(a.lower())
b = ''.join('(' if count[c] == 1 else ')' for c in a.lower())
```

The point here is that you don't want to count every single character more than once. For example, let's say you have the string `"eeeeee"`. You don't need to count six times. That's why you should use `collections.Counter`